# StackOverflowError occured when object is created globally why it is not OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

```
public class Abc {

Abc abc1=new Abc();
static Abc abc=new Abc();

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abc abc=new Abc();
   }
}
```

objects are stored in heap memory ,but here why im not getting OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: Because you have an infinite loop. Each call will add an element to the stack until the maximum number of entries on the stack is created. Each time an Abc is created, another Abc is created and so forth.

Comment: but if i make abc1 static there will be no errors ,im not getting it

Comment: Correct. Because static will only be created once. So the first Abc will create the static variables and once they are created they will never be created again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are constructing these objects recursively. In the constructor of `Abc` it creates a new object which in turn calls it's constructor.

The number of times you can call recursively is some where in the order of 1,000 to 10,000 times. The number of objects you can create are in the order of 1,000,000 to 20,000,000.

In short, you run out of stack long before you run out of heap.

You can add a field such as

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[10000000];
```

That way you are likely run out of heap before you run out of stack.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are overflowing the stack of resolution that is about 56k as far I remember before the memory goes out, try to create a ByteBuffer.create on each object if you want to test this.

The stack have the information from who called the code (the printStackTrace reads that stack for printing the code responsible) and have a limit on how it can increase, thats because recursion need to be replaced with iteration in some cases.

Comment: I'm old enough to have used a 56k dial up modem. ;)

Comment: Don't think the modem had 56000 entries :) i was old enough for 256k ones